# How to show Main Menu again upon exit?

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a simple menu for my program that I can switch between two modes easily after I enter EXIT.

The issue currently is once I enter EXIT my program shows the Menu but once I pick an option it proceeds to close.

I found similar posts on here but I seemed to try the answers given and had no luck.

```
int main(void) {
    int userChoice = 0;
    char userInput[100];
    int index = 0;

    userChoice = mainMenu();

    switch (userChoice) {
        case 1:
            printf("Enter EXIT anytime to quit out of loop.\n");
            while (strcmp(userInput, "EXIT") != 0) {
                printf("->");
                scanf("%s", userInput);
            }
            userChoice = mainMenu();
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}

int mainMenu() {
    int userChoice = 0;
    printf("--------------------------\n");
    printf("Option 1 \n");
    printf("Option 2 \n");
    printf("--------------------------\n");
    printf("Please enter 1 for Option 1 and 2 for Option 2 ->");
    scanf("%d", &userChoice);
    return userChoice;
}
```

Comment: Use a loop?....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you chose a menu choice for the second time, you don't attempt to do anything with it.  You just leave the `switch` and hit the `return` at the end.

You need to add another loop, and only show the menu at the top of the loop:

```
int main(void) {
    int userChoice = 0;
    char userInput[100];
    int index = 0;

    while (1) {
        userChoice = mainMenu();

        switch (userChoice) {
            case 1:
                printf("Enter EXIT anytime to quit out of loop.\n");
                do {
                    printf("->");
                    scanf("%s", userInput);
                } while (strcmp(userInput, "EXIT") != 0);
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I had the exact same code you posted and the issue that happens is, once I enter EXIT and  then pick 1 it wont allow me to enter anything again.

Comment: @lajuc See my edit.  You check `userInput`, which still contains the string "EXIT" from the last time through the loop.  Switch the `while` to `do...while` to perform the check at the end.

Comment: Thank you sir, totally forgot userInput still held EXIT. Works correctly now.